# How do implement sorting to this linkedlist?

Tags: python, sorting, oop, linked-list

So i need the data to be sorted from lowest to highest. So the pointer for the lowest value will point to the next highst and so on and so forth. So far it just points to the next one inserted regardless of the data.

I need it to be sorted as each value is appeneded

Code:

```
    def AppendNode(self, node):
    if self._isleagl(node):                         #just a error checking method
        if self.list_start == None:                 #checks if list is empty
            self.list_start = node      
            node._set_pointer(None) 
        else:                                       #list not empty
            item = self.list_start
            while item:
                if item == node:                    #Checks for duplicates
                    print("This is not allowed")
                elif item._get_pointer() is None:   #If it is end of the List
                    item._set_pointer(node)
                    node._set_pointer(None)
                    break
                else:                              #incrimets to the next node via pointer
                    item = item._get_pointer()
```

Current output:

```
 Index   Data   Pointer
   0      1       1
   1      6       2
   2      3       3
   3      7      None
```

Desired Output:

```
 Index   Data   Pointer
   0      1       2
   1      6       3
   2      3       1
   3      7      None
```

EDIT:

So ive implimented this, howerver it still doesnt work. I think its to do with the elif statements themself.

```
                elif item.data < node.data:
                    node._set_pointer(item._get_pointer())
                    item = item._get_pointer()
                    break
                elif item.data > node.data:
                    item._set_pointer(node)
                    item._get_pointer()
                    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler to write this from scratch than to try to fix code fragments -- hopefully a simple demo that shows the entire concept in practice helps get your code on the right track.  :)

```
from typing import Optional

class SortedList:
    """A list of ints that keeps itself in sorted order on insert."""
    def __init__(self, data: int):
       self.data = data
       self.next: Optional['SortedList'] = None

    def insert(self, data: int) -> 'SortedList':
        """Insert a new node into this list, and return the first node of the list."""
        node = SortedList(data)
        if node.data < self.data:
            # node is now at the head of the list
            node.next = self
            return node
        # Find the list node that will precede the new node.
        prev = self
        while prev.next is not None and prev.next.data < node.data:
            prev = prev.next
        # Insert the new node after prev.
        node.next = prev.next
        prev.next = node
        # Self remains the first node of the list.
        return self

    def print(self) -> None:
        """Print the list starting at this node."""
        print(self.data)
        if self.next:
            self.next.print()

sorted_list = SortedList(9)
sorted_list = sorted_list.insert(6)
sorted_list = sorted_list.insert(1)
sorted_list = sorted_list.insert(3)
sorted_list = sorted_list.insert(7)
sorted_list.print()
# output:
#  1
#  3
#  6
#  7
#  9
```

Comment: This is great, just one more question: it should be possible to implement deleting whith this way of doing it right?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  All you have to do is rearrange the "next" pointers so that they skip over the item that you want to delete.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the list in sorted order, you'll need to insert nodes in the middle sometimes rather than always putting them at the end:

```
# insert node after item
node.set_pointer(item.get_pointer())  # whatever followed item now follows node
item.set_pointer(node)                # node now follows item
```

Comment: How would i go about doing this? Do i need more elif statements to see if the data is > or < and if so where would they go and what else would i need inside them?

Comment: As you iterate down the list, look at `item` and `item.get_pointer()` to see if `node` goes in between them.  If `node` belongs after `item.get_pointer()`, keep iterating down.  Looking at the code you updated in your question, I think your condition is mostly correct, but you did not actually do the thing that I suggested in my answer to make sure that the node gets inserted correctly.

Comment: Im sorry i dont actually understand your suggestion givin in your answer and how to impliment it. Could you give a enxample of what should go inside one of the elif statements? EDIT:Sorry i didnt see your other answer